# How can I add a red border to an input field along with the required attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently if an input field with the `required` attribute is empty, it will display the browser's default error message. If I remove this attribute, it will display a red border on the input field because of my JavaScript code. How would I display both at the same time?

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  if (!title.value) {
    title.classList.add('error');
    setTimeout(function() {
      title.classList.remove('error');
    }, 300);
  }
});
```

```css
.error {
  position: relative;
  animation: shake .1s linear;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    left: -5px;
  }
  100% {
    right: -5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="title">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: check this https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/r/required/

Comment: Likewise you're adding class you can show or hide the span before the fields ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement it like this:

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // ....
});

$("form input").on("invalid", function(event) {
  $('#title').addClass('error');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#title').removeClass('error');
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.error {
  position: relative;
  animation: shake .1s linear;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
  border: 1px solid red;
  outline: none;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    left: -5px;
  }
  100% {
    right: -5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="title" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the CSS.

It is better to use it also for invalid fields (text in `type=number` field or any other invalid value).

```css
@keyframes shake3 {
    0% {left: -5px}
    16% {left: 5px}
    33% {left: -5px}
    49% {left: 5px}
    66% {left: -5px}
    80% {left: 5px}
    100% {left: 0}
} /* And @keyframes with prefixes */

input:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
  animation-name: shake3;
  animation-duration: .4s;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<input required >
```

If you want to show it only when you want, replace `input:invalid` by `.submited input:invalid` and add the `.submited` class to your form to activate styles.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't suit my needs as my JS code allows me to also shake the input field.

Comment: @TheCodesee you're shaking your element with CSS in the question - can you not just add the same CSS to `input:invalid`?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser I can, but the JS allows me to remove it after 300 milliseconds.

Comment: @TheCodesee CSS supports animations. See [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer, however I only wish for the styling to be applied after the submit button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function validate() {
  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  if (!title.value) {
    title.classList.add('error');
    setTimeout(function() {
      title.classList.remove('error');
    }, 300);
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="title" required>
  <input type="submit" onclick="validate()">
</form>
```

Changed from onsubmit to onclick and added visibility/emphasis to the border for demonstration purposes - it was harder to see with 1px and the timeout window.

Comment: Unfortunately this is no good as the border is applied to the input field as soon as it is clicked (not when the submit button is pressed).

Comment: @TheCodesee That was my mistake I added it to the submit now and it works as intended

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use `onclick` on button?

Then in case validation is ok, then you could programatically invoke `submit` on form.

```js
function validate() {
  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  if (!title.value) {
    title.classList.add('error');
    setTimeout(function() {
      title.classList.remove('error');
    }, 3000);
  } else {
     document.getElementById('form').submit()
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="title" required>
  <input type="submit" onclick="validate()">
</form>
```